# Tooltip using html javafx

Tags: java, html, styles, javafx, tooltip

I want to add a tooltip on a checkbox of javafx. I want to make it using java code. This tooltip text depends on some object properties. My problem is that i want to have some(not all) words bold inside the tooltip. Is there any way to do it? As far as i googled i didn't found a solution or a way to do it using for example html.
It would be a charm if i could do something like this:

```
PaggingTest paggingTest = new PaggingTest();
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(
    "<b>AlgorithmType:</b> " + paggingTest.getAlgorithmType()
    + "<br/><b>Memory Pages:</b> " + paggingTest.getMemoryPages()
    + "<br/><b>Program Pages:</b> " + paggingTest.getProgramPages()
    + "<br/><b>Sample Count:</b> " + paggingTest.getSampleCount()
    + "<br/><b>Distribution Type:</b> " + paggingTest.getDistributionType());

CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Test");
checkBox.setTooltip(tooltip);
testFlowPane.getChildren().add(checkBox);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
WebView  web = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = web.getEngine();
webEngine.loadContent
(
    "<b>AlgorithmType:</b> " + paggingTest.getAlgorithmType()
    + "<br/><b>Memory Pages:</b> " + paggingTest.getMemoryPages()
    + "<br/><b>Program Pages:</b> " + paggingTest.getProgramPages()
    + "<br/><b>Sample Count:</b> " + paggingTest.getSampleCount()
    + "<br/><b>Distribution Type:</b> " + paggingTest.getDistributionType()
);

Tooltip  tip = new Tooltip();
tip.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
tip.setGraphic(web);
```

You may have to apply some css styling to the webview to get it to blend in with your tip.

Comment: Very helpfull! I am able to add css and to give the style i wish. Thank you very much. +1